# Part of html not being rendered by thymeleaf

Tags: html, class, thymeleaf

Using thymeleaf, I'm trying to generate the following structure:

```
<li class="active">
    <a href="/bootstrap/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Charts<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
        <li><a href="/bootstrap/flot">Flot Charts</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I modified it as below:

```
<li th:each="menu : ${sideForm.menu}" th:class="${activeItem} == ${menu.item} ? 'active' : null">
    <a href="#" th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(menu.submenu)}" th:href="@{'/' + ${sideForm.parentMenu} + '/' + ${menu.item}}" th:text="#{${menu.title}}">Item</a>
    <a href="#" th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(menu.submenu)}" th:text="#{${menu.title}}">Item<span class="fa arrow" th:class="fa arrow"></span></a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level" th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(menu.submenu)}" th:class="'nav nav-second-level'">
        <li th:each="submenu : ${menu.submenu}">
            <a href="#" th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(menu.submenu)}" th:href="@{'/' + ${sideForm.parentMenu} + '/' + ${submenu.item}}" th:text="#{${submenu.title}}">Sub Item</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

It rendered as below:

```
<li class="active">
    <a href="/bootstrap/dashboard">dashboard</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Charts</a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
        <li><a href="/bootstrap/flot">Flot Charts</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I added `"<span class="fa arrow" th:class="fa arrow"></span>"`, why isn't it rendered in real html? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `th:text` from the `<a>` tag causes thymeleaf to replace its content with the given value, replacing also the `span` tag

```
<a href="#" th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(menu.submenu)}" th:text="#{${menu.title}}">
    <!-- everything in the <a> tag will be deleted by the th:text -->
    Item     
    <span class="fa arrow" th:class="fa arrow"></span>

</a>
```

You should wrap the title in another html tag such as a `span` or `th:block` (th:block doesn't get rendered after being processed)

```
<a href="#" th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(menu.submenu)}">
    <th:block th:text="#{${menu.title}}">Item</th:block>
    <span class="fa arrow" th:class="fa arrow"></span>
</a>
```

Or, with inline text:

```
<a href="#" th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(menu.submenu)}" th:inline="text" >
   [[#{${menu.title}}]]
   <span class="fa arrow" th:class="fa arrow"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise, I like last suggestion. By the way, how many if/unless do I have to use? for any th:text or th:href or anything else?

Comment: @mikezang Well, if you don't need them, you may not use any. Use them only if you want to validate a condition